# SUMIF (INDIRECT()) within ARRAYFORMULA() Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm trying to wrap a sumif(range) formula in an array formula.  The 'range' is dynamic, and is derived by an INDIRECT(ADDRESS()) combo, based on an input cell in this case $D$2.  I used this approach as R1C1 notation didn't work when referencing another sheet within an arrayformula.

The formula references the an input date ($D$2), and sums the value in each row, up to the lookup date(column).

I need to wrap the formula in an ARRAYFORMULA

The following formula works perfectly and returns a sum from the dynamic range.

```
=(IF(B6:B<>"", IF((isnumber(search("** Expenses",B6:B))=FALSE)+(B6:B:B="Total Expenses"), SUMIF(INDIRECT("Actual P&L!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),3,4,TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),MATCH(TEXT($D$2,"Mmm-YY"), 'Actual P&L'!$8:$8, 0),4,TRUE),TRUE),">=0"), SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Total "&B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),3,4,TRUE,"Actual P&L")&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total "&B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),MATCH(TEXT($D$2,"Mmm-YY"), 'Actual P&L'!$8:$8, 0),4,TRUE),TRUE),">=0")), ""))
```

for the purposes of this, I'll simplify it to;

```
=(IF(B6:B<>"",SUMIF(INDIRECT("Actual P&L!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),3,4,TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),MATCH(TEXT($D$2,"Mmm-YY"), 'Actual P&L'!$8:$8, 0),4,TRUE),TRUE),">=0"),"")
```

The IF() statement exists to get the formula to look at each row (and to skip rows that don't have data)

When I wrap it in an ARRAYFORMULA I just get 'zero' as the array output, although it does populate the rows and skips the blanks.

```
=arrayformula(if(B6:B<>"",SUMIF(INDIRECT("Actual P&L!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),3,4,TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B6:B,'Actual P&L'!B:B,0),MATCH(TEXT($D$2,"Mmm-YY"), 'Actual P&L'!$8:$8, 0),4,TRUE),TRUE),">=0"),""))
```

I have a dummy sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRqmodWmWxXaHb17IMfhcS22STHGzfEwzcfGN4ksLxo/edit#gid=1628413405)

Comment: The shared sheet has restricted acess

Comment: @rockinfreakshow thank you, and appologies.  I thought I'd updated that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B6:B,lambda(z,if(z="",,sum(ifna(filter(filter('Actual P&L'!C9:N,eomonth("1-"&'Actual P&L'!C8:N8,)<=eomonth(D2,)),'Actual P&L'!B9:B=z))))))
```

[image]

Comment: wow.. thank you so much.  this is very super cool.  I was fixated on an inefficient solution.